# How to fix blocked redirect due to CORS issues?

Tags: javascript, http, cors, deno

Here is my setup:

Running a local angular application on port 4200

Running an API using Deno on port 4300.

I have a use case where a client call at some api endpoint `http://localhost:4300/foo`, needs to redirect the user to another portion of the front end, say `http://localhost:4200/bar#baz`.

Currently this fails with the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4200/bar#baz' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4300/foo') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I have tried disabling/allowing cors on the API:

```
  ctx.response.headers.set('Acces-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  ctx.response.headers.set('Acces-Control-Allow-Headers','*');
  ctx.response.headers.set('Acces-Control-Allow-Methods','*');
  ctx.response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true');
```

But this does not work.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Without setting up a proxy or installing a browser plugin.

Thanks!

Comment: i mention it is a deno based api. Can you maybe mention the extra information you may require?

Comment: @Teemu Also the problem might not be with the server, it might very well be the client that needs to be configured. It is a bit hasty to conclude it is a server problem. The only thing that is certain is that, this is a CORS problem

Comment: CORS problem is a server configuration issue. If you're not specifically allowing CORS on the server, browsers can't access the requested page/response. Notice, that the original pre-flight request is made with `options` method, does your server set the CORS headers in that case?

Comment: Yes. I included the lines I have on the sever that should be updating the CORS settings

Comment: The error message gives you a hint: "_Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response._" I'm not familiar with deno, but it looks like `*` isn't accepted content in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, maybe you should consult the manual ..?

Answer (score 4):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers):

> The value "`*`" only counts as a special wildcard value for requests without credentials (requests without HTTP cookies or HTTP authentication information). In requests with credentials, it is treated as the literal header name "`*`" without special semantics. Note that the Authorization header can't be wildcarded and always needs to be listed explicitly.

You are making a request with credentials therefore you can't use `*` as a wildcard and have to be explicit about which headers you are using.